# Change CSS properties of body when link is clicked with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bunch of lightboxes that all have the **same class**, but separate ID's. When you click:

`<a class="lightbox" href="#lightbox_one">`

I want Javascript to add `overflow: hidden;` to `#page_wrap`. I want this to apply to all `<a>`'s with that class of `.lightbox` Then when the lightbox is closed using `<a href="#close">` I want the CSS properties to revert back to the original state (`overflow: scroll;`).

Here's my [**codepen.**](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/KCwmA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just want the page underneath to stop scrolling? Just apply `overflow:hidden` to the `body`

```
$(".lightbox").click(function(){
  $("body").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
});

$(".close").click(function(){
  $("body").css({"overflow":"auto"});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Some css:

```
.overflowHidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.overflowScroll {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

If you are using jQuery you could do this:

```
$('#content').on('click', '.lightbox', function() {
    $('#page_wrap').removeClass('overflowScroll').addClass('overflowHidden');
});
$('div[id^=lightbox]').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('#page_wrap').removeClass('overflowHidden').addClass('overflowScroll');
}
```

Comment: Awesome. @jmore009 had a slightly cleaner answer, but I'm glad to see a different method of achieving the same desired outcome. Thanks.